# How can I create an Azure Marketplace SaaS App using api/azure-cli/powershell/terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-marketplace

I'm trying to create [CloudAMQP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jEuL.png) in the azure marketplace in an automated way

Is there a way to do this using an api or any cli tools?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the CloudAMQP you use is a computer:

[image]

So actually, you will create a virtual machine to provide you the functions. Then you can use the Azure CLI command [`az vm create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_create) to automatically create the CloudAMQP.

Comment: Even though the category says compute it does not create a VM. It creates a SaaS app which is maintained by CloudAMQP

Comment: This command kinda does what I want, I still need to configure the account with the provider after the resource is created


az resource create --resource-type 'Microsoft.SaaS/resources' -g 'RG_NAME' --properties '{"offerId":"cloudamqp-v3","paymentChannelMetadata":{"azureSubscriptionId":"<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"},"paymentChannelType":"SubscriptionDelegated","publisherId":"84codes","saasResourceName":"<SAAS_NAME>","skuId":"bunny-1","status":"Subscribed","storeFront":"AzurePortal","termId":"hjdtn7tfnxcy"}' --name <SAAS_NAME> --location global